# Help getting CSS formatting correct

Tags: css, html, formatting, indentation

Grrr. Anyways,
I formatted all my code elements so that they indented 40px. Now, I have line breaks between my <span>? All of my italicized texts are supposed to be next to their respective code. Now, they are on a seperate line break.

If you check my source code, the spans have the following code:

```
<span class="taginfo">(<em>deprecated</em>)</span></code>
```

That's basically it. It was fine before I formatted the code to an indent. If it helps, another member on stackoverflow helped me format the code using this:

```
.substructure code{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 40px;
 line-height: 18px;
 font-size: 13px;
}
```

.substructure is the div id for my code sections

Comment: A more informative subject line might attract more readers.

Comment: Obviously, it attracted you so it must be fine.

Comment: Not really. Just came by to gave you that advice. Didn't read the question.

Comment: You must have a lot of time on your hands to keep revisiting my question and not read it.

Comment: It attracted me too, but only because I found it amusing. Honestly, I've no idea how to help you even after reading the post. Try posing a short html/css pair describing what you have, then tell us what it generates, and what you want it to generate.

Comment: So many downvotes because the title isn't great? Nothing wrong with the question itself.

Comment: I think your opening `<code>`-tag is missing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `display: block`. That basically turns a `span` into a `div`.

Comment: (Psssst: this is the part where you upvote and accept the answer.)

Comment: You also say that .substructure is the div **id** for your code sections. Either it must be one code section with `id="substructure"` in which case you must change it to #substructure in the CSS or it is a class name in which case you must put `class="substructure"` on your code sections.